$x\lt Sy\iff x\lt y\lor x=y$ can be deduced from Robinson arithmetic $Q$?
We can define new predicate symbol "$\lt$" in Robinson arithmetic $Q$ by adding the axiom $x\lt y\iff\exists z (x+Sz=y)$.With this definition, $Q$ can prove that (1) $\lnot(x\lt0)$  because for all $x$, $x+Sz=S(x+z)\neq 0$ by the axioms Q1 and Q5.
And we can also prove in $Q$ that (2) $x\lt Sy\iff x\lt y\lor x=y$. It is because if $x\lt Sy$, then  there is a $z$ such that $x+Sz=Sy$, so by the axiom Q2 and Q5, $x+z=y$ for some $z$. When $z=0$, then $x=y$ and if $z\neq 0$, then by the axiom Q3 $x\lt y$. Therefore $x\lt Sy\to x\lt y\lor x=y$. And if $x=y$, then $x+S0=S(x+0)=Sx=Sy$, so $x\lt Sy$. If $x\lt y$, then $x+Sz=y$ for some $z$, hence $S(x+Sz)=Sy$ for some $z$, but $x+SSz=S(x+Sz)$ for all $z$, so $x\lt Sy$. Therefore $ x=y\lor x\lt y\to x\lt Sy$.
But when I tried to prove (3) $x\lt y\lor x=y\lor y\lt x$, It was difficult for me. And Wiki says that the second one (2) cannot be deduced from $Q$.I think that (3) cannot be deduced from $Q$, and (2) actually can be deduced. Which argument is correct?

They define $x<y$ as $\exists z( Sz+x)=y,$ not $\exists z(x+Sz)=y.$

@spaceisdarkgreen is there a meaningful difference in Q?

@PW_246 Yes. Q can’t prove addition commutes. (Or that $0+x=x$, or many other  seemingly trivial universal statements.)

In fact I don’t think it proves (3) either, but I could be missing something. I don’t see how the case where $x$ and $y$ are nonzero can go through without induction. There are some half-universal instances of trichotomy it proves, though, I think.

(Or I guess I should say it proves the half universal instance…. there’s only one (scheme) of them.)
